# How can i use module.exports.function in es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert this code to es6 so for my react project, but I couldn't figure out(didn't get an error but couldn't achieve what I wanted to do).

here are the files.

```
foo.js

module.exports = () => {
console.log("hello default");
}
module.exports.bar = () => {
console.log("one functions");
}


index.js

const foo = require("./foo");
foo();
foo.bar();
```

I want be able to do this without using NAMED exports.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I couldn't figure it out" ? Did you receive an error or something?

Comment: I meant I couldn't understand how to do it. anyways Shubham Khatri has answered my question, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES6, you can make use of `export and import` instead of require and module.exports

```
export default () => {
   console.log("hello default");
}
export const bar = () => {
    console.log("one functions");
}
```

**index.js**

```
import foo, { bar} './foo';

foo();
bar();
```

**EDIT:** In order to replicate the same exact behaviour, you can leverage the fact the Javascript functions are essentially objects and you can assign more properties to them

```
const foo = () => {
  console.log("hello default");
};
foo.bar = () => {
  console.log("one functions");
};

export default foo;
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jlo3yv11o)

Comment: yes, i can use import and export, But i want to be able to execute this way,

import foo from './foo' and run foo(); , foo.bar();

Comment: A demo of what you want to achieve https://codesandbox.io/s/9jlo3yv11o

Comment: @AustonBarboza ,please let me know if the demo is what you want

Comment: Demo is a exactly what I wanted ...thank you..

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
function needsAName () => {
  console.log("hello default");
}

function bar () {
  console.log("one functions");
}

export default {needsAName, bar}
```

To use it:

```
import functions from './Container'

functions.needsAName()
functions.bar()
```

Comment: i tried this, it doesnt work the way i want, i want to be able to access foo() and foo.bar() without named exports.

Comment: @AustonBarboza I have edited my answer so you can do it without named imports. You can only have one default export hence exporting the object with both the functions in it